# GoogleAuthProvider does not persist/keep the login on refresh

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I installed create react app, set up the authentication firebase project in the console, and added authentication code.

I click the sign-in buttons, log in with google and the app displays my name. i hit refresh and my name disappears. When I used firebase last year, I stayed signed in. I believe the browser should keep my sign-in state.

How can I keep sign-in after reload?

here is a simplified bare-bone code:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { useState } from 'react'
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
//import { GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
//const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();


const auth = getAuth();

function App() {
  const [name,setName]=useState();
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      <button onClick={()=>{
signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
  .then((result) => {
    // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
    const token = credential.accessToken;
    // The signed-in user info.
    const user = result.user;
    setName(user.displayName)
    console.log('user:',user)
    // ...
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle Errors here.
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    const email = error.email;
    // The AuthCredential type that was used.
    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
    // ...
  });
  }}> sign in </button>
    <p>user: {name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the approach I've followed in one of my projects. I created a custom hook where I look for `onAuthStateChanged`. Now, even if you refresh the auth'ed user would be persisted.

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged, User } from '@firebase/auth';

import { app } from '../../configuration/FirebaseConfiguration';

const useAuth = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const auth = getAuth(app);

  let mounted = useRef<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    mounted.current = true;
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
      console.log("onAuthUserChanged", user);
      if (user) {
        if (mounted.current) {
          setUser(user);
        }
      } else {
        if (mounted.current) {
          setUser(null);
        }
      }
    });

    return () => {
      mounted.current = false;
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [auth]);

  return {
    user,
    auth,
  };
};

export { useAuth };
```

Here's a link to a sample github repository I created a while back https://github.com/SangeetAgarwal/FirebaseAuthReactRouterv6

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `reactfire` -- react hooks for firebase

```js
import { useUser } from 'reactfire';
const Auth = () => {
  const { status, data: user } = useUser();
  console.log('status', status, user)
  return (
    <div>
      {
        (status === 'loading') ?
          <span>loading...</span>
          :
          <h1>Welcome Back, {user && user.displayName}!</h1>
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```